# JavaScript - Add div after data element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a `div` after `pre` element that has a data attribute. So far, this is what I have:

**HTML**

```
<pre data-color="blue"></pre>
<pre data-color="blue"></pre>
<pre data-color="blue"></pre>
```

The result, after the JavaScript should be this:

**HTML**

```
<pre data-color="blue"></pre>
<div class="blue">Blue content</div>

<pre data-color="blue"></pre>
<div class="blue">Blue content</div>

<pre data-color="blue"></pre>
<div class="blue">Blue content</div>
```

So far my function looks like this:

**Javascript**

```
var blue = document.querySelectorAll("[data-color='blue']");

var insertdiv = document.createElement(div.class = 'blue', .textContent = 'Blue content.');


[].forEach.call(blue) {

  this.nextElementSibling.appendChild(insertdiv);
};
```

However the function isn't working at the moment. No jQuery please.

Comment: To use *forEach*, use something like: `[].forEach.call(blue, function(el){console.log(el.id);});` but that is not advisable since some browsers in use will not allow host objects to be treated like native objects. In the OP, even if the syntax is fixed, *this* within the function is undefined so defaults to the global object, and nothing is done with the parameters passed to the function, see [*Array.prototype.forEach*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

createElement does not work that way, you create the element *then* add properties.
Also, use a regular loop, using an empty array and `forEach.call()` doesn't do what you think it does.
And you can `insertBefore` the `nextSibling`, which would be the same as the non-existing `insertAfter` etc.

```
var blue = document.querySelectorAll("[data-color='blue']");

for (var i=blue.length; i--;) {
    var insertdiv = document.createElement('div');
    insertdiv.className   = 'blue';
    insertdiv.textContent = 'Blue content.';    

    blue[i].parentNode.insertBefore(insertdiv, blue[i].nextSibling);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dGj84/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Hey what about if I wanted to append it as a child of the nextSibling - like this http://jsfiddle.net/dGj84/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following.

```
var elems = [] ;
elems = document.getElementsByTagName("pre");

for(var i=0, i<elems.length; i++){
    var aDiv = document.createElement("div");
    aDiv.textContent = "Blue content";
    aDiv.className = "blue";
    elems[i].parentNode.insertBefore(aDiv, elems[i].nextSibling);
}
```